# How to design a microservice based application with each microservice having their own datasource?

Tags: java, spring-boot, microservices, rdbms

I am designing a microservice based application in which there are services that uses information from a MySQL db. There are two services - Booking Service and Payment Service.

Payment Service needs information from Booking Service.

How to design this using MySQL while keeping separate db for both the services? How to enforce the relational constraints between two tables which are on separate databases?

P.S: I am using Spring Boot to design the web services.

Comment: You can't enforce relational constraints between two separate databases - if you think you need to, your two services are too closely coupled to be individual microservices.

Comment: So Booking Payment Invoicing all these separate services must be clubbed into one service?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In microservices there is nothing called a relational consistency, your system should become eventual consistent.

Lets take your case, you have two microservices with diff. DB

- Booking
- Payment

Now lets say someone created a booking, now wants to pay for the booking using the payment service.

You must be thinking that is Payment Service i should check whether the booking exist or not or is the booking cancelled or not.

The above validations could be achieved but not 100% without creating a very high level dependency between the services and that is against the principles of microservices.

Let me give you a example:

1. Someone cancelled a booking while payment in progress - assume you processing a payment in Payment Service after checking booking is Ok from Booking Service , while payment is in progress someone cancelled the booking

Now as in this case temporarily system is in a inconsistent state, what you should do is from events on Booking Service like BookingCancelled, check if we took a payment , yes then start the payment reverse process , rather than checking all things at once.

> Go for a eventual consistent system in which both service listen to
>   events to one other and tries to be consistent.

Answer (score 1):

It is recommend for microservices to use different databases and maintain their own data ([PolyglotPersistence](https://www.martinfowler.com/bliki/PolyglotPersistence.html)).

Sharing of data across the API's should happen via API's.

In this case, if the payment service requires booking details, the details should be retrieved by making a call to the Booking service API.

For more details, here is the [link](https://www.martinfowler.com/articles/microservices.html) to microservices article by Martin Fowler.

Comment: I don't think the payment service should be calling the booking service API.  The payment service shouldn't even care nor know that a booking service even exists!  Instead the payment service should just listen to events to update its data store for eventual consistency with what it needs.  See techagrammer's answer that addresses this.

Comment: Polyglot persistence is orthogonal to separating the databases - you could have a monolith that talks to multiple different kinds of persistence, or a fleet of microservices that all use different instance of the same persistence technology.